# How to limit row number per group without change new page in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

Is there any way to limit row number per group without change new page in crystal report 2008. The reason i do that is due to customer using printer EPSON LQ 300 (dot matrix) always will print in landscape if detech my layout in landscape. Because they need the record always print in 1 page (Letter size) for 2 groups and each group must show 5 records. Example:

But, in CR2008, if you set the row per group from group section expert, definitely it will change to new page, but I do not want it change to new page. Any Idea?

In one page (Letter size):

```
Group Name: Customer-ABC

NO INVOICE AMOUNT

1) INV001 USD100

2) INV002 USD100

3) INV003 USD100

4) INV004 USD100

5) INV005 USD100

Group Name: Customer-ABC

NO INVOICE AMOUNT

6) INV006 USD100

7) INV007 USD100

8) INV008 USD100

9) INV009 USD100

10) INV010 USD100
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way to accomplish this with groups... but you might be able to employ a workaround and rig it to act like 5 records per group/10 per page. I am assuming the following for purposes of this illustration:

There may be invoice data for multiple clients in one report. Each page will display ten records maximum per page across two subsections. If, for example, there are less than 10 invoices for a given client the first section would display 5 invoices, the second second would display 4 and the invoice data for the **next** client would start over at the beginning of the next page.

**With that:**

You can accomplish this by creating a manual running total to track your record count per client group. You'll hide your actual group header, print the group header names in the detail lines, then use that record count along with a *remainder()* formula to conditionally hide or display the group names in the details, create new pages at certain intervals, etc. You will also use *recordnumber* - which will give you the actual current count of records across the entire report to separate section for each new client.

**Step overview:**

- Create a formula (we'll call it recordCount) that tracks the number of rows in each client group, resetting the count on the change of group (this will be a manual running total).
- Create two additional detail lines. Move one **above** your existing invoice detail line and leave one below.
- Suppress the existing Client GroupName header and footer.
- In both new detail lines (Da and Dc) add the GroupName.
- In Da, conditionally suppress the row if the recordCount is not equal to one.
- In Dc, conditionally suppress the row is the remainder of the recordCount divided by 5 is anything other than zero. Ex: remainder(recordnumber,5)<>0
- In Dc, set up a "New Page Before" to end the previous page on the condition that the recordnumber divided by ten is equal to zero.
- In GH1 set up a "new page before" that runs when *recordnumber* (not recordCount) is not equal to 1.

The result should be that the Da *looks like* a group header and displays the company name at the top of each group of 5 records. The "New Page before" in Dc will force a new page to be created after every 10th record *within each client group*. The GH1 "page before" will force a new page to start each time the client changes but the condition prevents it from occurring for the first group in teh report. If you have a separate report header page you may not care about that anyway.